# Angular 7 behavior subject with class object

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular7, behaviorsubject

I have below class

```
export class filter {
    public PageRecords: number;
    public SearchText: string;
    public SortColumn: string = null;
    public SortDirection: string = null;
    public StartingPos: number;
}
```

Below behavior subject

```
filterParam = new BehaviorSubject(new filter);
```

Updating subject

```
this.filterParam.next(<filter>{StartingPos  : 1,PageRecords : 10 })
```

When I get the value of subject

```
this.filterParam.value
```

It only have two props StartingPos and PageRecords which I updated. it lost other props.

How to resolve this?

Comment: this.filterParam.next(value) creates  a whole new object with value as input, is like to: this.filterParam = new filter(value), so you didn't update the object, you created a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you don't pass directly a Filter object class. You are casting some dynamic json to a filter object but only with this two properties.

You can do something like this:

```
const filterParam = new filter();
filterParam.StartingPos = 1;
filterParam.PageRecords = 10;

this.filterParam.next(filterParam);
```

**EDIT:**
I didn't notice that you want just update two values from the BehaviorSubject value. As @ritaj suggested in a comment below this aswer you can do something like he suggested:

```
this.filterParam.next(Object.assign(this.filterParam.value, {StartingPos: 1, PageRecords: 10 }
```

> Object.assign() copies the values (of all enumerable own properties) from one or more source objects to a target object. It has a signature of Object.assign(target, ...sources). The target object is the first parameter and is also used as the return value. Object.assign() is useful for merging objects or cloning them shallowly.

Comment: If I do new filter() then what about if I set other props at some other function, then it will lost other updated value.Otherwise I need to take first like this.filterParam.value,  then updated value, I though when i passing two values it should update only those

Comment: You will lose them anyway if you do `this.filterParam.next(<filter>{StartingPos  : 1,PageRecords : 10 })`

Comment: You can do `this.filterParam.next(Object.assign(this.filterParam.value, {StartingPos : 1,PageRecords : 10 }` to keep the old values.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the meaning of the name of your class parameters, I think you want one single `filter` class and you just want to notify others when this filter is changed.

I recommend this code:

```
filter = new filter;
filterParam = new BehaviorSubject<filter>(this.filter);

// later change the filter like this
changeFilter() {
  this.filter.StartingPos = 1;
  this.filter.PageRecords = 10;
  this.filterParam.next(this.filter);
}
```